# CSS class to add space between the Controls

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, user-controls

I am using 3 radio buttons in my User Control, I need to add space between the Radio Buttons, not between the text or button and its text, but between the buttons, could you please help me how can I add space between the Radio Buttons, my User Control list is as follows

```
public class RadioButtonListAppointmentFormat : MyCalSTRSRadioButtonList
{
    public RadioButtonListAppointmentFormat(): base()
    {
        this.CellPadding = 0;
        this.CellSpacing = 0;

        Items.Add(new ListItem("In Person", "InPerson"));
        Items.Add(new ListItem("Telephone", "Telephone"));
        Items.Add(new ListItem("Web Based", "Web"));

        SelectedIndex = 0;
        this.SetDisplayTextToNoWrap();
    }
}
```

Base class for our User Control

```
public class MyCalSTRSRadioButtonList : BaseRadioButtonList
{
    public MyCalSTRSRadioButtonList() : base()
    {
        this.CssClass = ApplicationSettings.CssClass.FormText;
    }
}
```

this is the CSS it is using

```
.formtext {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 22px !important;
}
```

And following is to attach the css to the User Control

```
public static string FormText
 {
     get { return "formtext"; }
 }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated please

Comment: It would be better to post just the relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: That's all I have ralph

Comment: What @ralph.m means is that to troubleshoot the problem we need to start not with your source code, but with the generated code being sent to the browser. Use your browser inspector and copy the HTML/CSS from there into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 .formtext {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 22px !important;
    }

.formtext input[type="radio"] {
    margin-right: 10px; /* Puedes ajustar el valor según sea necesario */
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Cristian, what shall I do to apply this change only to the elements of this User Control not on other controls, how should I call this in.cs file, should I create a different property? Thank you so much my friend.

Comment: Hi Cristian for some reason its not reflecting on the UI my friend, even when I added margin-right: 10px; to the .formtext and .formtext input in both cases, UI remain the same, any help my friend why its not updating the UI, I cleared the Cache also.